# Object context lost inside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    axios.get('https://www.behance.net/v2/users/user/projects/4889175?api_key=' + 'API')
    .then(function(response) {
      var data = response.data.projects;

      for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++) {
        Behance.findOne({ name: data[i].name }, function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          if (!user) {
            console.log(this.name);
            // var newBehance = new Behance({
            //   name: this.name,
            // });
            // newBehance.save(next);
          }
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I'm pulling projects from Behance w/ their API and trying to save each one to a DB if it doesn't already exist using `findOne`. Inside of the for loop `data[i].name` returns a value, but inside of the `findOne` function it returns undefined.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening..

Comment: Try changing `var i=0` to `let i=0`.

Comment: your `console.log` inside `findOne` is for `this.name` - did you try `data[i].name` there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're logging out `this.name` instead of `data[i].name`. As far as I can tell, `this` is `window`.

You can use `.forEach` to simplify things a bit:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  axios.get('https://www.behance.net/v2/users/user/projects/4889175?api_key=' + 'API')
    .then(function(response) {
      response.data.projects.forEach(({name}) => {
        Behance.findOne({ name }, function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          if (!user) {
            console.log(name);
            // var newBehance = new Behance({
            //   name,
            // });
            // newBehance.save(next);
          }
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```